# Connection to database from another server: Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was trying to use a PHP script from server A to connect to a database on server B which returned the error:

> Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I used the exact same code which works for scripts on server B.

```
//Database parameters
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "abc_abc";
$password = "abc";
$dbname = "abc_abctable";

//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

And I have already used `tracert` on command prompt to check and whitelisted the IP Address of server A on the database on server B. And I also allowed all access and permission for user abc to access the abctable.

I think I saw a tutorial that I have to create my database username in this format: abc:[IP Address of server A] but I can't because cpanel doesn't have that option. It only allows 6 characters for username.

Comment: Well if server A and B are not the same box/IP then using `localhost` is not going to work... You need to use the IP or the DNS name of the db server to connect.

Comment: as @prodigitalson says, change localhost above to name or ip of serverb and you should be good to go. localhost is a special name which refers to the local computer (127.0.0.1 or ::1). So when on serverA it points to serverA, and on ServerB it points to serverB.  What is happening is that you are connecting to the local DB server on serverA which doesn't have either doesn't have that DB created, or has different User/Pass.

Comment: @prodigitalson Tried that and now I got this error: Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xx.x' (113)

Comment: That means your MySQL server's firewall is not open to outside connections. You should contact your hosting company that runs the server to ask them whether you can access it from outside their network.

Comment: @MosheKatz Thanks. I guess you're right. I _POST the form data into a script in server B and it worked.